# How to add 1 to last number?

Tags: vb.net

i use label for a order number.i want it add 1 to order number each time the order is placed. do i need do a loop ? And if so, how?

```
Private Sub btnprint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnprint.Click
    'ordernumber = 0

    ordernumber = ordernumber + 1
    Lblorn.Text = ("Order Number:" & ordernumber)
```

Comment: Are you getting errors?  What's the issue?

Comment: Why would the print button increase the ordernumber?

Comment: Is this ASPX by chance?

Comment: Sorry for my English. It is my second language. I am getting help formulating my questions now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop in this case as incrementing the order number should happen only when the `btnprint_Click` event is triggered.

A loop is required if you want to keep printing an `n` number or orders once the event is triggered.

You need to declare a variable which is global to the form/window where this button and the label is present and that will keep the latest `ordernumber` in memory - only till the window is open. Once you close the application, and open it again - it will be defaulted to `0`.

If you want this latest `ordernumber` available in other parts of the application, you need to declare the `ordernumber` as a global variable, in the application level.

If you want to store the value of latest `ordernumber`, even after the application is closed or after , you need to store it in a database or file and retrieve it while the application is loaded again.

Comment: Thank you very much. How do i declare the ordernumber as a global variable, in the application level.?

Comment: @Sophia Without knowing more about your application, it will be difficult to comment on that. You can learn more in here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx, look specifically for Project-Level Scope...

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking at that now.